# Issue doing mongo import to Azure Cosmos Emulator

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to restore data to the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator from MongoDB in order to test my Application.  I originally used the Data Import Tool but realised after reading the Documentation this is for use with the SQL API for Cosmos DB while I want to be using the MongoDB API.

I successfully exported my Data from Mongo to json file with the command line:

```
D:\MongoDb\bin>mongoexport.exe --db Vehicles --collection Cars --out C:\Temp\Cars.json
2018-09-18T10:02:21.210-0400    connected to: localhost
2018-09-18T10:02:21.212-0400    exported 100 records
```

I am then trying to import this into Azure Cosmos DB Emulator with below command

```
D:\MongoDb\bin> mongoimport.exe --host localhost:10255 -u admin -p C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw== --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --db Vehicles --collection Cars --type json --file "C:\Temp\Cars.json"
```

However I am getting the following Error:

```
2018-09-18T11:00:38.829-0400    Failed: error connecting to db server: Database Account admin does not exist
ActivityId: ada5953a-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0
2018-09-18T11:00:38.830-0400    imported 0 documents
```

I had created a DB in the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator called Vehicles with a Cars collection so not sure what I am doing wrong - or can the Azure Cosmos Emulator not be used for what I am attempting?

I tried changing the admin to Vehicles in the command line script but get the same error.

From the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator this is my Mongo Connection string which is where I was pulling the details from for the import

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

Ideally I want to get the Emulator running as a way to test things locally

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` as the user name? By that I mean. in the mongiimport.exe string use `-u localhost` instead of `-u admin`.

Comment: yeah - I just tried @localhost:10255/admin

Comment: No, no port. Just localhost. Like this: `D:\MongoDb\bin> mongoimport.exe --host localhost:10255 -u localhost -p C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw== --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --db Vehicles --collection Cars --type json --file "C:\Temp\Cars.json"`

Comment: @NickChapsas = just localhost worked - cheers....again :) :)

Comment: No problem :) I added the answer.

Comment: @NickChapsas - ok will mark as accepted when enough time has elapsed to let me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180278/discussion-between-ctrl-alt-defeat-and-nick-chapsas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DatabaseAccount name in the CosmosDB emulator is `localhost` not `admin` so your mongoimport.exe string should look like this:

```
D:\MongoDb\bin> mongoimport.exe --host localhost:10255 -u localhost -p C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw== --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --db Vehicles --collection Cars --type json --file "C:\Temp\Cars.json"
```